# php, substr edit

Tags: php

ok so im making a file system viewer.
   Im stuck on this though, I have everything working fine except when the I click the back button on the gui I have made.

So I have a string like so

http://www.grubber.co.nz/update/index.php?dir=../developer/_social_development

The script will go to the folder **/developer/_social_development**

but when I want to go back I press the back button and it will go back to the top directory so it goes all the way back to the first '/' for example **http://www.grubber.co.nz/update/index.php?dir=../**
I use this code to get back to the last page which doesn't work

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$marker = "/";
echo $str = (substr($dir, 0, (strpos($dir, $marker) + strlen($marker))));
```

all it does is remove everthing to the first '/' but I want it to goto the last '/' for example it was this **/developer/_social_development** and when I click on the previous folder i want it to be **/developer** also the string will change depending on what folder you are in so I cant just remove a set amount of characters

Thanks for the help

Comment: you can use `explode()` which converts `/developer/_social_development` into array so easily you can go prev and next

Comment: Not really to do with your question but you do realise you can do this dont you? Can cause security vulnerabilities: http://www.grubber.co.nz/update/index.php?dir=../../../../../../../

Comment: @Adam hehehe I didn't relise :-D, i just started this project off project like a hour ago so I have a few bugs :-D, ill fix them soon, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using another method str pos, you may use explode. here complete code:

```
$dir = '../developer/_social_development';
$marker = "/";
$arrDir = explode('/', $dir);
array_pop($arrDir);
$dir2 = implode( '/', $arrDir);
echo $dir2;
```

result: ../developer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strpos() which gives you the position of the first occurrence of a character in a string you should use [strrchr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) that will give you the position of the last occurrence of the character in your string

Answer (score 0):

Not a pretty best solution, personally I'd use a RegEx approach, but if you wanted to use str position you could do something like:

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$marker = "/";
echo $str = strrev(substr(strrev($dir), (strpos($dir, $marker) + strlen($marker))));
```

Or a RegEx based solution:

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
echo $str = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+$/", "", $dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = '/foo/bar';
$path = $path . '/..'; // /foo/bar/..
echo realpath($path); // Shows /foo
```